# Command "expo doctor" failed. npx -y expo-doctor exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: android, ios, react-native, build, expo

I get this error when trying to make my application live with Expo Application Service (EAS). But construction continues. I initialized my application with expo bare workflow.

Running "expo doctor"

Running 10 checks on your project...

✔ Check Expo config for common issues

✔ Check package.json for common issues

✖ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly

✖ Check for common project setup issues

✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema

✔ Check npm/ yarn versions

✖ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK

✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally

✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages

✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Detailed check results:

Advice: Use 'npx expo install --check' to review and upgrade your dependencies.

Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo version:

react-native@0.69.6 - expected version: 0.69.9

Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.

Install individual packages by running npx expo install react-native@0.69.9

Found outdated dependencies

The package "expo-modules-core" should not be installed directly in your project. It is a dependency of other Expo packages, which will install it automatically as needed.

This project has native project folders but is also configured to use Prebuild. EAS Build will not sync your native configuration if the ios or android folders are present. Add these folders to your .gitignore file if you intend to use prebuild (aka "managed" workflow).

This project has multiple package manager lock files (yarn.lock, package-lock.json). This may cause EAS build to restore dependencies with a different package manager from what you use in other environments.

One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.

Command "expo doctor" failed.
npx -y expo-doctor exited with non-zero code: 1

Comment: npx expo install --fix